# What control is telerik asp.net mvc UI demo layout using

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, layout, telerik

When we browse to telerik demo page for any one of the controls for it's asp.met mvc ui kit, I want to know what control are they using for the layout of the page or are they custom creating the layout of the page.

The layout is, you have the header on top, the search box and the navigation boxes on the left, in the main content area you have the 'theme chooser' drop down on the top and the entire content area below this theme chooser bar.

I can't post the image of it because I'm a new user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a custom layout created for the demos themselves, not a control. Download them and examine the site to see how it is implemented.

Comment: That's what I thought, but was hoping against it :-). Thanks

Comment: The WebForms suite has a similar control, though: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/page-layout/overview/defaultcs.aspx
It cannot, however, work under MVC, it is bound to the WebForms engine and lifecycle, so partial views, cshtml, etc. cannot accommodate it. Nevertheless, some food for thought.